# document.getElementById().innerHTML appears to be conflicting with my Jquery click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, onclicklistener, getelementbyid

I've got two javascripts on a page:

One is a script that gets some JSON from a server and then builds out some navigation markup and writes it to a div.

The other is a script that does *something* on click of one of the nav items.

So basically,

```
document.getElementById("writeNav").innerHTML += writeNav;
```

would replace:

```
<ul id="writeNav" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
 <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>Home</span></a> </li>    
</ul>
```

with:

```
<ul id="writeNav" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
 <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>Home</span></a> </li>   
 <li class="nav-item "> <a id="undefined" class="nav-link" href="#"><span>link 1</span></a></li>
 <li class="nav-item "> <a id="undefined" class="nav-link" href="#"><span>link 2</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

The Jquery, for the purpose of troubleshooting, would just launch an alert onClick of any of the ".nav-item" classes.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.nav-link').click(function(){
            alert('click function was called.'); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I comment out the "getElementById" line and click "home" it triggers the alert.  If I don't comment it out, and click "home", it does not trigger the alert.

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: well are you adding the items before or after you bind the event? If you overrwrite innerHTML it unbinds everything. You basically erase a whiteboard and have to write everything again.

Comment: I'm doing '''document.getElementById("writeNav").innerHTML += writeNav;''' in the window.onload = function().  The jquery is in a different script, introduced below it. ( $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.nav-link').click(function(){
   alert('click function was called.');
   $('.nav-link').removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
  });
 });)

Comment: Rule of thumb: never use `innerHTML +=`. With jQuery, there’s even an easy alternative: `$("#writeNav").append(writeNav)`.

Comment: Oh cool. Thanks Ry, that's definitely way easier.  But I'm still having the conflict. for some reason the jQuery in the .click() function still doesn't work on the items that are written with the 'append'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use appendChild method. Appending the elements directly with += operator probably affecting all the elements and their defined behavior under the `<ul>` element.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

```
let elementToAdd = // 
document.getElementById("writeNav").appendChild(elementToAdd);
```

Comment: Thanks. This lets me add all the elements, but I'm having trouble getting the classes on them in a nested structure or adding the href to the A element.  (ie: <li class="someclass"><a class="otherclass" href="#"><span>text</span></a></li>)

Comment: I couldn't understand your problem exactly. Can you enlighten me if the following answer won't help you.

var item = document.getElementById("id of the element");
item.classList(); // returns you the classes of the element
item.setAttribute("class", "something"); // sets an attribute
item.setAttribute("href", "#");
item.setAttribute("disabled", ""); // You can also set attributes like disabled this

It is up to you to create the algorithm that you need.
You can try the dev console to test your code.
Lastly you can check websites like w3schools for tutorials.